# Error executing AWS Lambda Sink Connector

Tags: aws-lambda, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am trying to execute AWS Lambda Sink Connector. I am getting below error.

```
[2021-04-21 02:01:39,104] INFO [AdminClient clientId=aws_lambda_sink-license-manager] Metadata update failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.internals.AdminMetadataManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=fetchMetadata, deadlineMs=1618970499263) timed out at 9223372036854775807 after 1 attempt(s)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The AdminClient thread has exited.
[2021-04-21 02:01:39,174] ERROR WorkerConnector{id=aws_lambda_sink} Error while starting connector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: License topic could not be created
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=createTopics, deadlineMs=1618970499103) timed out at 1618970499104 after 1 attempt(s)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
```

My connector Configuration is given below

```
{
 "name": "aws_lambda_sink",
 "config": {
 "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.aws.lambda.AwsLambdaSinkConnector",
 "tasks.max": "1",
 "topics": "mm.test.cecl.lambda",
 "aws.lambda.function.name": "kafka_lambda_sink_connector",
 "aws.lambda.invocation.type": "async",
 "aws.lambda.batch.size": "1",
 "aws.lambda.region": "us-east-1",
 "aws.access.key.id": "*************",
 "aws.secret.access.key": "***********",
 "behavior.on.error": "fail",
 "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": "sp-dev-broker-0.streawsnprd.massmutual.com:9092,sp-dev-broker-1.streawsnprd.massmutual.com:9092,sp-dev-broker-2.
streawsnprd.massmutual.com:9092,sp-dev-broker-3.streawsnprd.massmutual.com:9092,sp-dev-broker-4.streawsnprd.massmutual.com:9092,sp-dev-broker-5.streaws
nprd.massmutual.com:9092,sp-dev-broker-6.streawsnprd.massmutual.com:9092 ",
"reporter.bootstrap.servers": "sp-dev-broker-0.streawsnprd.massmutual.com:9092,sp-dev-broker-1.streawsnprd.massmutual.com:9092,sp-dev-broker-2.streawsn
prd.massmutual.com:9092,sp-dev-broker-3.streawsnprd.massmutual.com:9092,sp-dev-broker-4.streawsnprd.massmutual.com:9092,sp-dev-broker-5.streawsnprd.mas
smutual.com:9092,sp-dev-broker-6.streawsnprd.massmutual.com:9092 ",
 "consumer.override.sasl.jaas.config": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"kafka_connect\" password=\"*******\";"
}
}
```

What is causing this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to create the Confluent license topic manually? Otherwise, the error could be the SASL config there does not apply to the AdminClient, only the consumer

Comment: @OneCricketeer _confluent-command topic is already there. I am using kafka-connect which is admin account in sasl jaas config.

Comment: Where did you configure the Connector SASL config for the AdminClient?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I didn't. How do I do that ?

Comment: I'd suggest trying `admin.override.sasl.jaas.config`. I'm not exactly sure though since I haven't used Connect with a SASL secured cluster

Comment: If that doesn't work, you can try `export KAFKA_OPTS` as shown here before running `connect-distributed` command https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/index.html#jaas-configurations